# No php completion in PhpStorm

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, code-completion

I have a problem in phpStorm.
It does not autocomplete php basic functions like `var_dump`, `array_keys`...

If it may help : I moved phpstorm from a folder in my user folder to /opt folder.

Comment: I'm not a Linux/Mac user .. but have you tried `File | Invalidate caches...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LazyOne I could not test it on ubuntu but it may be the quickest solution

Finally I removed all .idea folder on each project, and it worked !

Answer (score 5):

Another thing to check is if your file cache is corrupt, try: File > Invalidate Caches
(warning this will delete your local history)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after reinstalling PhpStorm on Ubuntu 16.04. After reopening an old project it would not autocomplete built-in functions. I was able to fix that buy going to `File>Settings>Languages & Frameworks>PHP>PHP runtime (a tab)` then putting a check mark on 'PHP runtime'
[image: screenshot]

For some reason these were not checked.